# Issue with localtime() in perl

Tags: perl

```
my ($sec, $min, $hour, $mday, $mon, $year, $wday) = localtime(time);
$wday = ('Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat')[$wday]
$year += 1900;
printf FILES "$year/$mon/$mday %02d:%02d:%02d ", $hour, $min, $sec;
```

Print outputs the date value of root user not the one from which script is running.Any idea about this.

Comment: How do you know that the root user and the script user are different?  How do you know that those two users have different time zones?  Prove it, please.

Comment: Since Perl 5.10, Perl now includes [Time::Piece](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html). I highly recommend that you use that instead of the older `localtime` and `timelocal` interface. It does a lot of the work for you.

Comment: @pilcrow i fired "date" command for both user (root and other) and got different value

Answer (score 1):

You also need to add 1 to the month, as `localtime` returns it zero-based, and you should use format specifiers in the `printf` so that the field sizes are constant.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my ($sec, $min, $hour, $mday, $mon, $year, $wday) = localtime;
$wday = qw( Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat )[$wday];
$year += 1900;
++$mon;
printf "%s %4d/%02d/%02d %02d:%02d:%02d\n", $wday, $year, $mon, $mday, $hour, $min, $sec;
```

**output**

```
Tue 2015/03/17 14:06:36
```

Or you can make use of [`Time::Piece`](https://metacpan.org/module/Time::Piece) very effectively here.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Piece;

print localtime->strftime('%a %Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S'), "\n";
```

**output**

```
Tue 2015/03/17 14:06:36
```

Comment: do u have same date value for root as well as other user. If yes i agree with your solution...because i  my case values are different and hence root value is returned with this code

Answer (score 0):

`time()` will give you UTC.

`localtime` will adjust based on `$ENV{'TZ'}` - the only thing I can think of that might be causing your problem, is that if this isn't set correctly. Try printing it as part of your script.

[`Time::Piece`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html) is a good module for this:

```
$t->tzoffset            # timezone offset in a Time::Seconds object

$t->strftime(FORMAT)    # same as POSIX::strftime (without the overhead
                        # of the full POSIX extension)
$t->strftime()          # "Tue, 29 Feb 2000 12:34:56 GMT"
```

You can print time as formatted *including* timezone (Which should tell you what's up).

Does something like this work for you:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::Piece;

$ENV{'TZ'} = 'UTC';
Time::Piece::_tzset();

my ($sec, $min, $hour, $mday, $mon, $year, $wday) = localtime(time);
$wday = ('Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat')[$wday];
$year += 1900;
$mon++;

printf "$year/$mon/$mday %02d:%02d:%02d ", $hour, $min, $sec;
print "\n";

$ENV{'TZ'} = 'UTC-8';

Time::Piece::_tzset();

($sec, $min, $hour, $mday, $mon, $year, $wday) = localtime(time);
$wday = ('Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat')[$wday];
$year += 1900;
$mon++;

printf "$year/$mon/$mday %02d:%02d:%02d ", $hour, $min, $sec;

$ENV{'TZ'} = 'PST8PDT';

Time::Piece::_tzset();

($sec, $min, $hour, $mday, $mon, $year, $wday) = localtime(time);
$wday = ('Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat')[$wday];
$year += 1900;
$mon++;

printf "$year/$mon/$mday %02d:%02d:%02d ", $hour, $min, $sec;
```

(And yes, I know that's importing `Time::Piece` but not using it - I wanted to reproduce the original code as much as possible).

Comment: You can't. System time is system time. `time()` queries system time, and returns a number of seconds since Jan 1st 1970. In UTC. For anything else you need a timezone offset.

Comment: OK, sorry, yes. Misunderstood. Checking `$ENV{TZ}` between the two would therefore be relevant.

Comment: we can you need to put localtime link to /usr/share/zoneinfo/PST8PDT or UTC or  other with root user , but my point is not that how it is different but point is it should give date value of user or not..

Comment: If you `echo $TZ` what do you get?

Comment: for root i get nothing ...for user i get PST

Comment: I have a suspicion that'll not be a valid timezone. I've edited answer with a test. But: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PST8PDT

Comment: valid or not but it gives date value..... thanks for your workaround ..but still my doubt is not clear why it gave root date value ...

Comment: I think because it defaults to UTC when it's unsure, so in effect it's just ignoring the PST setting.